# Why passing directly Promise.all to a .then function throws an error?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass directly `Promise.all` to a `.then` function like:

```
const test = [
    Promise.resolve(),
    Promise.resolve(),
    Promise.resolve(),
    Promise.resolve()
];

Promise.resolve(test) // It's supposed to be an AJAX call
.then(Promise.all) // Get an array of promises
.then(console.log('End');
```

But this code throws an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Promise.all called on non-object`.

When I remove the shorthand syntax, it works:

```
Promise.resolve(test)
.then(queries => Promise.all(queries))
.then(console.log('End'));
```

So why a `Promise.all` passed directly to a `.then` throws an error ? (And why a `console.log` works fine ?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to bind `Promise.all.bind(Promise)`

From ES2015 [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.all):

> The all function requires its this value to be a constructor function that supports the parameter conventions of the Promise constructor.

Or better use it directly on array.

```js
const test = [
    Promise.resolve(1),
    Promise.resolve(2),
    Promise.resolve(3),
    Promise.resolve(4)
]

Promise.resolve(test)
  .then(Promise.all.bind(Promise))
  .then(x => console.log(x))
  
Promise.all(test)
  .then(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: Why ? (I can't use it directly on array, this array come from an Ajax call, I'll update my question)

Comment: @RChanaud [Spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/#sec-promise.all) says so "Let C be the this value.
If Type(C) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception." "
The all function requires its this value to be a constructor function that supports the parameter conventions of the Promise constructor."

Comment: @RChanaud I doubt your ajax request magically returns promises. So there is still a place where you create a an array of promises inside `then` callback so you could return `Promise.all(promises)` instead of an array

Comment: Thank you, I'm using a one line `map` in the previous then, that's why I got an array of Promises directly. I wanted to wait for all those promises to be fulfilled in the next then.
Regarding the specs, I don't understand the purpose of it, why `.then(console.log);` works and `.then(Promise.all);` don't ?

Comment: @RChanaud "I don't understand the purpose of the spec" well `all` uses `this` internaly to create new promise it later returns. Read steps 11. BTW `console.log` is not a part of ecma. It is API described by different standard https://console.spec.whatwg.org/